# lowest latency method to pass raw video frames from ffmpeg to gstreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to pass raw audio and video buffers from ffmpeg to gstreamer. For video a 1920x1080 25fps RGB output is what ffmpeg is producing.

What is the best method to pass this from ffmpeg to gstreamer on the same hardware.

The end goal is to not block either ffmpeg from outputting if gstreamer cannot take the frame and to not block gstreamer if no frames are available.

For this we have looked at sockets and tcp/udp plugins. However if we get any buffering issues the gstreamer pipline will block until the buffer is clear/full.

we will have multiple pairs of TX/RX running on same linux instance so stdI/O will not work.
Is there a current preferred method for this type of transfer?